# android class.getInterfaces() return empty

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My code is just like this:

```
// ITest.java
interface ITest {


}

// TestA.java
class TestA implements ITest {


}

// TestB.java
class TestB extends TestA implements ITest {


}

// main function
void main() {

TestB testB = new TestB();
Class[] interfaces = testB.getClass().getInterfaces();

// The count is 0 when gradle version is 7.x
int count = interfaces.length();

}

// build.gradle
android {
   buildTypes {
      debug {
        minifyEnabled true
      }
  }

}
```

If gradle version is 7.x , the `interfaces.length()` is 0. Such as:

```
Gradle version -> 7.6.3
Android Gradle plugin -> 7.4.2
```

If gradle version is 6.x, the `interfaces.length()` is 1. Such as:

```
Gradle version -> 6.5.1
Android Gradle plugin -> 4.1.2
```

If gradle version is 7.x and `minifyEnabled false`, the `interfaces.length()` is 1. Such as:

```
Gradle version -> 7.6.3
Android Gradle plugin -> 7.4.2

android {
   buildTypes {
      debug {
        minifyEnabled false
      }
  }

}
```

I must upgrade gradle version to 7.x in my android project and `minifyEnabled true` so, how can I solve this problem??? I expect `interfaces.length()` is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following ProGuard rule to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
# Keep the ITest interface
-keep interface your.package.name.ITest
```

Replace `your.package.name` with the actual package name where `ITest` is located. This rule instructs ProGuard to keep the specified interface and prevent it from being removed during the minification process.

After adding this rule, rebuild your project with minification enabled, and the `interfaces.length()` should return the expected value.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: I think it may be because both TestA and TestB implement the ITest, but TestB inherits from TestA and has indirectly implemented the ITest. Gradle has optimized it during compilation and removed the ITest interface directly implemented by TestB. But how to avoid this optimization?

Comment: then you should keep all the interfaces in the pro-guard rule. Here is the code snippet 
for example: 
-keep interface * {
    *;
}